# lltd process taking lot of memory and CPU time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx

I am running rails app on `nginx+unicorn` on `aws` 8GB server, there is one process `lltd`. I have no clue what this process is about. I am not sure should I kill it or not as it may be a system process.

This is my `top` command log

```
22824 ubuntu    20   0        4 S 138.2  4.4 241156:32 lltd                                                                                                                                                                       
23283 ubuntu    20   0     4104 R  48.5  4.2   1:26.94 ruby                                                                                                                                                                       
31631 mysql     20   0      0 S   8.6  4.1 264:54.60 mysqld                                                                                                                                                                     
23293 ubuntu    20   0    4288 S   1.3  6.5   2:40.30 ruby                                                                                                                                                                       
   36 root      20   0      0 S   0.7  0.0 103:33.00 kswapd0
```

can anyone help with me with this?

I tried google this but there are not results on this.

Comment: You can get more info with `cat /proc/22824/cmdline` (replacing the process id as necessary).

Comment: @kdgregory - thanks for ur reply..but there is no result when i execute this command

Comment: If that's the case, then the process wasn't running any more. You could also look for it in the standard locations: `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/sbin`, `/var/lib/...`.

Comment: @kdgregory - thanks for the reply `22824 ubuntu    20   0  425024 364816      4 S 163.8  4.5 243992:51 lltd` its is still running. I will check these locations as well